# ROSARIA catkin_make error

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROSARIA package in my laptop. I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 and using ROS indigo. I follow the tutorial [How to use ROSARIA](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA).  But when I try to use `catkin_make` to build **rosaria** package I am getting the following error message.

```
traversing 1 packages in topological order:
- rosaria

+++ processing catkin package: 'rosaria'
==> add_subdirectory(rosaria)
Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
Boost version: 1.54.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
thread
rosaria: 1 messages, 0 services
Configuring done
Generating done
Build files have been written to: /home/fan/catkin_ws/build
Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/fan/catkin_ws/build"
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target _rosaria_generate_messages_check_deps_BumperState
Scanning dependencies of target rosaria_gencfg
[  0%] [ 16%] [ 16%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/RosAria.cfg: /home/fan/catkin_ws/devel/include/rosaria/RosAriaConfig.h /home/fan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosaria/cfg/RosAriaConfig.py
../catkin_generated/env_cached.sh: 16: exec: /home/fan/catkin_ws/src/rosaria/cfg/RosAria.cfg: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [/home/fan/catkin_ws/devel/include/rosaria/RosAriaConfig.h] Error 126
make[1]: *** [rosaria/CMakeFiles/rosaria_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 16%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 16%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 16%] Built target _rosaria_generate_messages_check_deps_BumperState
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213935/rosaria-catkin_make-error/) by [ROS_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23215/ros_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like the `RosAria.cfg` file is not exectuable. This is required for `dynamic_reconfigure` to work.
So do a

```
chmod a+x /home/fan/catkin_ws/src/rosaria/cfg/RosAria.cfg
```

and try again.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2015-07-17**:
Oops, my fault.  I've now fixed it in the repository, anyone encountering this can pull from it again, or just manually fix it as in migs answer.   Thanks!

**Comment by [ROS_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23215/ros_fan/) on 2015-07-17**:
Thank you, now it works :)